# Laravel websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Всем привет! Я использую библиотеку https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets. И мне нужно чтобы когда я запускаю websockets с помощью команды php artisan websockets:serve после этого вызывался кастомный метод или скрипт в котором я бы мог отловить момент запуска и вызвать метод создания пользователя итд

Answer (score 0):

Перед непосредственным выполнением консольной команды Laravel запускает событие [CommandStarting](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Console/Events/CommandStarting.html)

Подпишитесь на него и в его слушателе можете реализовать все то, что необходимо сделать до запуска команды.

Документация по работе с событиями в Laravel здесь: https://laravel.com/docs/master/events.