# Laravel Websockets запуск скрипта в backgound

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Я разрабатываю сайт c сокетами https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets я сделал чат, уведомления, но есть так же игра (график который поднимается и опускается) он должен одинаково отображаться в режиме реального времени у всех и мне нужно чтобы он работал даже тогда, когда никого нет на сайте, чтобы скрипт был запущен в background не в зависимости открыл ли я сайт в браузере или нет. К примеру я стартую php artisan websockets:serve и далее нужно стартануть скрипт который будет работать постоянно. Как это можно реализовать?

Смотрел тут https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы стартовал скрипт и работал background постоянно.

Заранее спасибо большое за любую помощь!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Laravel websockets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975234/laravel-websockets)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Работа websocket сервера похожа на работу демона очереди - работает в фоне постоянно.
Для разработки достаточно ввести в консоли проекта `php artisan websockets:serve`, чтобы запустить websocket сервер. Эта команда запускает демон (аналогично команде `php artisan queue:work`). Но как ты уже понял, если нажать CTRL+C в консоли или просто закрыть консоль - выполнение команды прекращается.

Для этого есть различные менеджеры процессов (сейчас речь только про linux). Один из самых распространенных - [`supervisor`](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B2+supervisor) (не офф. ссылка). Устанавливаешь этот сервис, настраиваешь его. В документации к очередям laravel [есть пример настройки](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration). Перечитай еще раз.

По-русски:

1. Устанавливаешь supervisor;
2. Создаешь в директории `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` файл конфигурации, например `laravel_websocket.conf`
3. Содержимое конфига редактируешь под себя - прописываешь действительные пути к своему приложению (где лежит `artisan`), и к файлу логов, куда они будут писаться

```
[program:laravel_websockets]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan websockets:serve
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

4. Запускаешь управление указанной командой

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel_websockets:*
```

Проверяешь: `ps -aux | grep artisan` - в списке процессов есть выполнение этой команды